# Pandas column of variable length numpy arrays, create new arrays based on dict lookup of the arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking for a performant or vectorized way to accomplish this scenario where I have an initial column (called "data") consisting of variable length arrays and create a new column (or it could be a numpy array) where the values in the original arrays are replaced by some looked-up value from a dict.

In my example, the output column "lookedup_values" is what I'm trying to create quickly.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

def map_my_values(row):
  return [lookup.get(val) for val in row]

lookup = {10: 234234, 20: 253458, 30: 99934, 40: 90083, 50: 55847, 70: 99938, 100: 325230}

df = pd.DataFrame([
                   {'id':1234, 'data': np.array([10, 20, 30])},
                   {'id':1235, 'data': np.array([50, 70])},
                   {'id': 1236,'data': np.array([20, 10])},
                   {'id': 1237,'data': np.array([100, 30, 50, 10])}
])
df['lookedup_values'] = df['data'].map(map_my_values)
df.head()
```

```
     id               data                 lookedup_values
0  1234       [10, 20, 30]         [234234, 253458, 99934]
1  1235           [50, 70]                  [55847, 99938]
2  1236           [20, 10]                [253458, 234234]
3  1237  [100, 30, 50, 10]  [325230, 99934, 55847, 234234]
```

It's trivial to use .map or apply and iterate over the array in my column 'data', but it's quite slow on a dataset of tens of millions of rows. I'm hoping someone may know of a vectorized solution or approach.

I have provided a full / working demo above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to decrease the runtime is using [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/)

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba_map(row):
    lookup = {10: 234234, 20: 253458, 30: 99934, 40: 90083, 50: 55847, 70: 99938, 100: 325230}

    return np.array([lookup[val] for val in row])

df['lookedup_values'] = df['data'].map(numba_map)
```

---

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) column `data` before mapping and [`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by index

```
x = df.data.explode().map(lookup)
df['lookedup_values'] = x.groupby(x.index).apply(np.array)
df
```

Out:

```
     id               data                 lookedup_values
0  1234       [10, 20, 30]         [234234, 253458, 99934]
1  1235           [50, 70]                  [55847, 99938]
2  1236           [20, 10]                [253458, 234234]
3  1237  [100, 30, 50, 10]  [325230, 99934, 55847, 234234]
```

---

### Micro-Benchmark

On a colab instance with 2 cores and 12 GB RAM the pandas solution is ~10x slower than the original solution with comprehensions. I didn't expected that.

Results show len(df)/4 on the x-axis

[image: results]

Code for the benchmark

```
import pandas as pd

def map_my_values(row):
  return [lookup.get(val) for val in row]

lookup = {10: 234234, 20: 253458, 30: 99934, 40: 90083, 50: 55847, 70: 99938, 100: 325230}

from numba import njit
@njit
def numba_map(row):
  lookup = {10: 234234, 20: 253458, 30: 99934, 40: 90083, 50: 55847, 70: 99938, 100: 325230}
  return np.array([lookup[val] for val in row])

def makedata(n=1):
  return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([
                   {'id':1234, 'data': np.array([10, 20, 30])},
                   {'id':1235, 'data': np.array([50, 70])},
                   {'id': 1236,'data': np.array([20, 10])},
                   {'id': 1237,'data': np.array([100, 30, 50, 10])}
])]*n).reset_index(drop=True)

def comprehension(df):
  df['lookedup_values'] = df['data'].map(map_my_values)
  return df

def explode(df):
  x = df.data.explode().map(lookup)
  df['lookedup_values'] = x.groupby(x.index).apply(np.array)
  return df

def numbamap(df):
  df['lookedup_values'] = df['data'].map(numba_map)
  return df

import perfplot
perfplot.show(
    setup=makedata,
    kernels=[comprehension, explode, numbamap],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(5,18)],
    equality_check=False
)
```

Comment: can you explain what explode does?

Comment: `explode` takes values that are containers and transforms every item inside the container into a single row. I added a reference to the documentation.

Comment: isnt `.apply(np.array)` will slow down the process?

Comment: This does work, though it's slower than my original approach using map. The time it takes to create "x" is 3x longer than my approach using map, no?

1000 loops, best of 3: 290 µs per loop (original)
1000 loops, best of 3: 834 µs per loop (creating x)

Comment: @jrjames83 - added benchmarks, you were right. My solution is not prefarable.

Comment: @jrjames83 - I tried some alternatives without success. The solution I added uses `numba`. The improvement is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSzczesny for the thoughtful analysis and the Numba example. I'll mark your answer as correct and continue to play around with it, updating the thread with any new benchmarks if I find any other approaches.